# Cambiar Baudrate (en Raspian Jessie) para comunicación serial

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, debian

Estoy tratando de enviar y recibir datos entre una Raspberry Pi y Servos dynamixel AX-12 (Sin USBDynamixel). He conseguido habilitar el puerto `ttyAMA0` de mi Raspberry (Raspbian Jessie) para realizar comunicación serial pero los servos no reciben ni envian nada.

Pienso que puede ser por el baudrate pues mediante C kermit ví que éste puerto tenía un baudrate=9600 y necesito cambiarlo.

¿Cómo podría cambiar el baudrate?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 <VELOCIDAD>
```

Tendrás que hacerlo en cada reinicio de la Pi.

Comment: Muchas Gracias :) Ya lo voy a probar...

Answer (score 0):

En esta página, http://www.stlinux.com/install/getting-started/serial, muestra como hacerlo:

```
host% kermit

(/) C-Kermit> set line /dev/ttyS1
(/) C-Kermit> set baud 9600
/dev/ttyS1, 9600 bps
(/) C-Kermit> set carrier-watch off
(/) C-Kermit> set flow-control none
(/) C-Kermit> c
Connecting to /dev/ttyS1, speed 9600
Escape character: Ctrl-\ (ASCII 28, FS): enabled
Type the escape character followed by C to get back,
or followed by ? to see other options.
----------------------------------------------------
STMicroelectronics Base Distribution version 2.3

target login:
```

Comment: Ya lo probe asi pero no se que pueda ser porque al ingresar el C-Kermit> set baud ....... No acepta otro valor que no sea el 9600 :/  ..... GRACIAS POR EL APORTE!!!

Comment: Te recomendaria que uses minicom o putty :D